# Why the function is failing in case of numbers greater than 48 digits?

Tags: c++, algorithm, biginteger, number-theory

I am trying to find

> (a^b) % mod

where b and mod is upto 10^9, while l can be really large i have tested upto 48 digits with success
using this relation

> (a^b) % mod = (a%mod)^b % mod

```
#define ll long long int
ll powerLL(ll x, ll n,ll MOD)
        {

        ll result = 1;
   

 while (n) {
        if (n & 1)
            result = result * x % MOD;
        n = n / 2;
        x = x * x % MOD;
    }
    return result;
}


ll powerStrings(string sa, string sb,ll MOD)
{


    ll a = 0, b = 0;


    for (size_t i = 0; i < sa.length(); i++)
        a = (a * 10 + (sa[i] - '0')) % MOD;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++)
        b = (b * 10 + (sb[i] - '0')) % (MOD - 1);

    return powerLL(a, b,MOD);
}
```

powerStrings("5109109785634228366587086207094636370893763284000","362323789",354252525) returns **208624800** but it should return **323419500**. In this case a is 49 digits

powerStrings("300510498717329829809207642824818434714870652000","362323489",354255221) returns **282740484** , which is correct. In this case a is 48 digits

Is something wrong with the code or I will have to use other method of doing the same??

Comment: Did you verify that you're  not overflowing your long long int .?

Comment: 354252525 is not a prime, so reducing the exponent modulo `MOD - 1` is not correct

Comment: `long long` is commonly 64 bits (I know of no system where it's larger). A 64-bit integer type can hold values up to 19-20 decimal digits. If you want to handle larger values you need either a larger type or other algorithms.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude he's already using an other algorithm: reducing the inputs first

Comment: @harold in others case when i am using non -prime it works , i don't think something is wrong with it

Comment: why you're doing `b = (b * 10 + (sb[i] - '0')) % (MOD - 1);`?

Comment: you said b is up to 10^9 so just read it as long long, as others pointed out `% MOD - 1` does not work in all cases

Comment: @appleapple its from fermat's theorem to reduce b

Comment: @Photon yes , removing it makes it work , thanks

Comment: `#define ll long long int` - Blech!   I stopped reading as soon as I saw that abomination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because it is not mathematically correct.

In general, we have that `pow(a, n, m) = pow(a, n % λ(m), m)` (with `a` coprime to `m`) where `λ` is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). As a special case, when `m` is a prime number, then `λ(m) = m - 1`. That situation is also covered by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). That's only a special case, it does not always work.

`λ(354252525) = 2146980`, if I [hack that in](https://ideone.com/K3QK5D) then the right result comes out. (the base is not actually coprime to the modulus though)

In general you would need to compute the Carmichael function for the modulus, which is non-trivial, but feasible for small moduli.